# How to extract all td's text content from an element in the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to extract td's text content and store each one into an array from another array that contain the following contents:

```
//create two element in the array, that store a string containing html code

tablecontentArray[0] = "`<tbody><tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 1</td><td>Fruit 2</td></tr><tr><th>Title 3</th><th>Title 4</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 3</td><td>Fruit 4</td></tr></tbody>`"

tablecontentArray[1] = "`<tbody><tr><th>Title 5</th><th>Title 6</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 5</td><td>Fruit 6</td></tr><tr><th>Title 7</th><th>Title 8</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 7</td><td>Fruit 8</td></tr></tbody>`"

//loop to extract the td text content from the each element of the tableContentArray and store it into extractedTdArray 

    extractedTdArray = [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "`<tbody><tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 1</td><td>Fruit 2</td></tr><tr><th>Title 3</th><th>Title 4</th></tr><tr><td>Fruit 3</td><td>Fruit 4</td></tr></tbody>`"
var extractedTdArray = str.split("<td>")
  .filter(function(v){ return v.indexOf('</td>') > -1})
  .map( function(value) { 
    return value.split("</td>")[0]
  })
  console.log(extractedTdArray)
```

First you split up the string into arrays by `<td>` you get

```
0:"`<tbody><tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th></tr><tr>"
1:"Fruit 1</td>"
2:"Fruit 2</td></tr><tr><th>Title 3</th><th>Title 4</th></tr><tr>"
3:"Fruit 3</td>"
4:"Fruit 4</td></tr></tbody>`"
```

Then you get the elements that have the closing `</td>` in  with the `filter`

```
0:"Fruit 1</td>"
1:"Fruit 2</td></tr><tr><th>Title 3</th><th>Title 4</th></tr><tr>"
2:"Fruit 3</td>"
3:"Fruit 4</td></tr></tbody>`"
```

then you split it by the `</td>` and get the first element. we already split by `<td>` so we know that from the beginning is the info we want to the `</td>`.

`["Fruit 1", "Fruit 2", "Fruit 3", "Fruit 4"]`

Comment: That is great. But what if the td is like is different for example one might contain <td valign="top"> and another <td valign="top" align="center">?

Answer (score 0):

setting one table and push

```
var extractedTdArray = [];// create result array

// loop across html strings
$.each(tablecontentArray, function (key, table) {
    $('#table').html(table);//create html table
        // loop across the created table td's
        $.each($('#table').find('td'), function (key2, td) {
            var tdVal=$(this).text();// td value
            //push to array
            extractedTdArray.push(tdVal);
        });
    });
});
```

setting multiple tables and map

```
// set tables
$.each(tablecontentArray, function (key, table) {
    $('#table' + key).html(table).addClass('table');
});

// map td
var extractedTdArray = $('.table tr:has(td)').map(function (i, v) {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your code does? it would also help to understand if you could provide a fiddle link as well.